# Проблемный многопоточный код

Tags: java, многопоточность

У меня есть такой участок кода:

```
private List<NtId> getNtIds(List<String> ids) {
    List<NtId> ntIdList = new CopyOnWriteArrayList<>();

    int step = 10000;
    int stepsNumber = ids.size() / step + ids.size() % step == 0 ? 0 : 1;

    CountDownLatch countDownLatch = new CountDownLatch(stepsNumber);
    for (int i = 0; i < stepsNumber - 1; ++i) {
        int current = i * step;
        new Thread(() -> {
            ntIdList.addAll(ntIdRepository.findDistinctByNtIdIn(ids.subList(current, current + step)));
            countDownLatch.countDown();
        }).start();
    }

    int lastStep = stepsNumber * step;
    new Thread(() -> {
        ntIdList.addAll(ntIdRepository.findDistinctByNtIdIn(ids.subList(lastStep, lastStep + ids.size() % step)));
        countDownLatch.countDown();
    }).start();

    try {
        countDownLatch.await();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return ntIdList;
}
```

Смысл его заключается в том, что на вход поступает список из `id` и по ним надо выгрузить объекты. База данных не принимает список более 1000 значений и поэтому, чтобы ускорить процесс делаю обработку во многих потоках.

Проблема в том, что при изменениях переменной `step` меняется и результат, чего быть не должно. В чем я ошибаюсь и как можно улучшить этот участок ?

Comment: а почему не использовать Future?

Comment: @Mikhail Vaysman в чем преимущества использования Future? просто самому интересно =)

Comment: @MikhailVaysman покажите пример относительной этой задачи ? Не совсем понимаю, что мне это даст в данном случае.

Comment: @MikhailVaysman Да, возвращает список объектов типа NtId.

Comment: @LexHobbit код будет проще

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Возможно вам подойдет вот такой вариант.

```
private static List<NtId> getNtIds(List<String> ids) {
    int step = 100;
    return split(ids, step).parallel()
            .map(l -> ntIdRepository.findDistinctByNtIdIn(l))
            .flatMap(List::stream)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Этот метод я взял тут [Partition a Java 8 Stream](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32435407/690987). Но вы можете использовать аналогичный из **Guava** или любой другой библиотеки.

```
private static Stream<List<String>> split(List<String> list,  int size) {
    int parts = (list.size() - 1) / size;
    return IntStream.range(0, parts + 1).mapToObj(n -> list.subList(n * size, n == parts ? list.size() : (n + 1) * size));
}
```

В этом решении есть подводные камни - оно использует `ForkJoinPool.commonPool()`. А он используется внутри системы повсеместно.

Что бы запустить это внутри своего **pool**, надо сделать так

```
ForkJoinPool forkJoinPool = new ForkJoinPool(2);  

forkJoinPool.submit(() ->  
    split(ids, step).parallel()
                .map(l -> ntIdRepository.findDistinctByNtIdIn(l))
                .flatMap(List::stream)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());  
).get();
```

---

Вот вариант с использованием **Future**

```
private static List<NtId> getNtIds(List<String> ids) {
    // размер pool можно подобрать
    ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);

    List<Future<List<NtId>>> futures = new ArrayList<>();
    int step = 100;

    int parts = (ids.size() - 1) / step;
    for (int i = 0; i < parts + 1; i++) {
        final List<String> subList = ids.subList(i * step, i == parts ? ids.size() : (i + 1) * step);
        futures.add(executor.submit(() -> ntIdRepository.findDistinctByNtIdIn(subList)));
    }

    List<NtId> ntIdList = new ArrayList<>();

    for (Future<List<NtId>> future : futures) {
        try {
            ntIdList.addAll(future.get());
        } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {
            // игнорирю
        }
    }
    executor.shutdown();
    return ntIdList;
}
```

Comment: Отличный ответ. Спасибо огромное!

Comment: Единственный вопрос - можно ли как-нибудь ограничить количество потоков в первом варианте решения ? Скажем, я хочу, чтобы одновременно выполнялось не более 20 действий. Это можно как-то реализовать ?

Comment: добавил эту информацию в вопрос

Comment: Отлично! Не подскажите, как стрим узнает, что он запускается внутри какого-то внешнего пула ?

Comment: это особенности реализации. стрим будет использовать пул в котором запустили.